# Damping Constant for a Ball Rolling in a Bowl

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, friction

How would you find the damping constant of a ball rolling without slipping in half of a sphere? I know how to find the period of the oscillation, but how would I find the damping constant experimentally? Thank you for the help, and side note: I do not know Calculus and the Physics class is AP at high school level.

Comment: The damping constant as in $B$ from $x(t)=Ae^{-Bt}\cos(Ct+D)+F$?

Comment: Yes. I don't understand how to use that equation experimentally by only knowing the mass of the ball, the period of the ball, and the radius of the bowl. What can I use to find that?

Comment: Can you measure the amplitude of the oscillations at any time?

Comment: Yes, from the radius.

Comment: But if it is damped, then the amplitude decreases on the next oscillation. Can you measure the oscillation of any given cycle? Or just the initial amplitude?

Comment: Just the initial amplitude and period.

Comment: If all you can measure is the initial amplitude, period, and mass of the ball. Then, mathematically speaking, you don't even know if the oscillations are damped or not

Comment: @Jim I was thinking on the same lines as you - typing the answer below - also I wonder if your equation above might only work at low amplitude at the bottom of the bowl because the spherical shape and the rotational energy of the ball will complicate so it is not simple harmonic motion (or even damped simple harmonic motion)

Comment: @Mara is this an actual experiment or a thought experiment?

Comment: Would there be a way to find the constant if I knew the period of oscillation at every point in time?

Comment: This is a thought experiment. It was preposed in class, and supposedly there is a way to find it.

Comment: The way I see it, if you know the position of the ball at every moment in time (or the height above the base) then you would see the amplitude decrease (as Jim was suggesting in his comments)- plot position of the ball on a graph then use the $Ae^{-Bt}$ term from Jim's equation to fit the drop in amplitude.... but I don't think it is as simple as that - or to put it another way, that may give a reasonnable way of measuring the damping constant, but I think it is approximate and not exact.

Comment: @Jim can't edit my comment above about your equation - I like the exponential term and think your first comment is the most useful. So I think it would be a good approximation to use.

Comment: What do the variables in the rest of the equation stand for. The only equation we learned for this was Ae^(-bt/2m)Cos(omega*t)

Comment: What does C, D, and F stand for?

Comment: Looking at your equation I think the damping term is $b$ - and you need to monitor position with time. Think about the maximum value of you $cos$ function and consider making a graph of log(amplitude) against time - think about what happens when you take log of your equation.

Answer (score 1):

See https://www.andrew.cmu.edu/course/24-352/Handouts/logdecrement.pdf and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_decrement

For a damped oscillation you measure the peaks, and record the decreasing amplitudes. From that you calculate the log decrement $$\delta = \frac{1}{n} \ln \left( \frac{x_0}{x_n} \right)$$

where $x_0$ is the initial amplitude and $x_n$ is the amplitude after $n$ peaks. The damping ratio now is $$\zeta = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{2\pi}{\delta}\right)^2}}$$

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v1): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of first link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.

Comment: The link is course notes from Carnegie Melon. I do not know who the author is, or what the course# this relates to.

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it movement of a rolling ball in a bowl shaped like half a sphere may be quite tricky to model exactly and the equations may not be straightforward

The one thing that is certain is that damping causes energy to be lost from the motion and you can measure the ammount of energy whenever the ball gets to the highest point of the oscillation. So I wonder if you could get some information about damping by looking to see how the maximum height above of the ball changed each time it oscillated. This would show you how the total energy drops with time. Ideally you woudl get a plot of height of the ball above the base against time.

I guess you would need to use a video camera/webcam and a thinish glass bowl.

Hope this is helpful.

edit - another thought - it you say start the ball at one height in the bowl and have a circular line lower down around the bowl at a constant height you could get a measure of the damping by seeing how long it takes for the oscillations to become smaller and not rise above the line.